# Conectar banco externo ao UI Designer no Bonitasoft Community

Tags: jdbc

Estou utilizando a ferramenta `Bonitasoft` para desenvolver um projeto **BPM**, possuo um banco de Dados **PostgreSQL** que através de uma conexão **JDBC** consegui inserir e alterar registros pelo **Bonitasoft**, porém não consigo selecionar os dados do banco e exibi-los no meu **UI Designer**, por ser uma ferramenta ainda não muito utilizada não encontrei muita informação sobre a mesma, se tiverem daqui a pouco algum material, ou alguma ideia de como posso exibir os dados em uma planilha no meu **UI Designer**, seria muito útil.

Testei o retorno que meu `Select` me traz e as informações bateram corretamente com o que eu preciso, então adicionei as informações em um `arrayList`, meu problema agora é exibir as informações desse Array no UI Designer

Comment: Bom, nunca tinha ouvido falar no bonitasoft, mas quem sabe se você postar um pouco do seu código e onde está tentando exibir os registros...

Comment: É que na verdade por ser uma ferramenta BPM a própria ferramenta Bonitasoft se encarrega de gerar os códigos automaticamente por trás.

Comment: Entendo. É complicado então alguém sugerir alguma resposta, só pra quem já utilizou mesmo esta ferramenta. Pois não tem como ter noção onde se aplicaria o código.

Comment: Essa era a ideia @CarlosAndrade caso alguém soubesse mesmo, ou tivesse alguma ideia para seguir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após muita pesquisa e auxilio de um usuário com mais experiência e conhecimento da ferramenta, consegui exibir as informações que estão em meu banco de dados externo no meu UI Designer.

Inicialmente tive que configuraram uma variável **API REST** que apontasse para meu BDM:

`../API/bdm/businessData/com.hss.model.TransportadoraPostgreSQL?q=find&p=0&c=100`

**Onde:**

- `TransportadoraPostgreSQL` é o nome do meu BDM.
- `q=find` é a minha **query** que encontra tudo que esta no BDM.
- `c=100` é a quantidade máxima de registros do BDM que serão exibidos

Configuração da Variável API REST:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Configuração da Tabela onde será exibido os registros:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]